# Alternate of GetUserManager in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, owin

I am converting an existing Asp.net Mvc project to .Net Core now the issue is this get method

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {



return _userManager ??
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

In Mvc we could fetch OwinContext using

> HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager()

but in case of .Net Core GetOwinContext not present , When I compare definition of HttpContext of both classes
[image]

[image]

HttpContextBase is type in case of Mvc but in case of Core there is HttpContext which has no extension method in same namespace as HttpContextBase that's why this extension method was not found  ,Please let me know how to do this in Core?

[image]

Comment: Just use dependency injection instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: then please let me know how to inject this as dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alternate. ASP.NET Core uses dependency injection for pretty much everything. If you need `UserManager<TUser>`, you inject into the constructor of whatever class you're working with (controller, etc.):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public MyController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: is it guaranteed UserManager will be presented in service provider?

Comment: @anatol I believe it is, as long as you add the identity services to the collection when configuring your application, i.e. `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()`

Answer (score 2):

For accessing `UserManager` from `HttpContext`, you could try to implement an extension like below:

```
public static class HttpContextExtension
{
    public static UserManager<TUser> GetUserManager<TUser>(this HttpContext context) where TUser: class
    {
        return context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.GetUserManager<IdentityUser>();
        return View();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: actually @ChrisPratt has only answered this and I just forgot to accept

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Kindly accept the answer which resolve your issue.