# GetUserManager from OWIN in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm migrating an existing .NET *Class* project to Core. Here we are trying to get current usermanager from owincontext, Can you please help how we can acheive this in .NET core?

I've tried using HttpContext but they no longer have OWINContext or GetUserManager()

```
    private CustomStore _myStore;
    private MyContext _dbContext;
    private AppUserManager _userManager;
    private AppRoleManager _roleManager;


    public CustomManager(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        _dbContext = ctx
                .GetOwinContext().Get<MyContext>();
        _userManager = ctx
            .GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserManager>();
        _roleManager = ctx
            .GetOwinContext().Get<AppRoleManager>();
    }
```

Comment: Always check for similar questions before crafting your own. Oddly, this same question was just asked 3 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097042/alternate-of-getusermanager-in-asp-net-core. I'd close this one as a dupe, but cannot currently because it has no upvoted or accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

For another option, you could implement your own extensioin to get the `UserManager` like

```
public static class HttpContextExtension
{
    public static UserManager<TUser> GetUserManager<TUser>(this HttpContext context) where TUser: class
    {
        return context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
    }
}
```